# m pages are printed, and the number of pages misprinted is never even. Why is any of the m-1 events $E_i =$ {misprint in the ith page} are m.i.?

Tags: probability, proof-explanation, independence

("m.i." = "mutually independent")

My understanding is that the conclusion is equivalent to saying that amongst a particular set of $m-1$ events, any one of those events would not depend on any subset of the remaining $m-2$ events. Is this interpretation correct and if so, how did the property of the printer lead to this conclusion?

Comment: As far as I can see, your interpretation of the question is correct, but the statement that you want to prove is false, even in the simplest case $m=3$. For example, I could have a printer that flips a fair coin, misprints the first page if the coin comes up heads, misprints the second page if it comes up tails, and never misprints the third page. The number of pages misprinted is always $1$, hence never even, and $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not independent.

Comment: That's what I thought. I will go back to ask the author. Thank you anway!